# Python: How to Set Default Permissions for Created Files and Directories

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, permissions

We've been working in a RedHat 7.9 Linux environment with a Python 2.7 script that writes data to files in a directory structure.  The directories and files created by the script in this environment are all set with 755 permission. This is the desired permission for the data.

We've now spun up a new environment in RedHat 8.6.  The scripts and data directory area that is written to is a mounted volume and the same volume used by the RedHat 7.9 environment.
We now are able to run the identical python scripts and write the data to the same shared volume.

The same user with the same umask default setting is used in both environments.
But in the RedHat 8.6 environment, all the directories and files created by the script have 700 permission.  That's not the desired permissions setting.

Python 2.7 is installed in each of the two environments on a volume different than the shared mounted volume that has the scripts and data.

I know that it's possible to change the Python code to explicitly specify the permission of the files, but there would be a lot of places in the script where files and directories are created, and I'd prefer not to have to change the Python code.

It seems like there is a difference in the environment or the config settings of Python that is causing the difference in behavior.  What could be controlling it?

Comment: Just an fyi, you wouldn't have to change the script everywhere files and directories are created, just call `os.umask()` at the beginning. But it would be good to identify what's different in the new environment.

Comment: *is a mounted volume and the same volume* ... NFS? Samba? What are the mount options? If NFS, which version are you using in either? Are ACLs in place/supported? Either way, this doesn't smell like a **programming problem** to me...

Comment: The suggestion by sj95126 to just use os.umask() at the beginning of the script worked for me.  It does seem like there is an environment difference but I'm not going to investigate further now.  Thanks